# Sound stopped working on a dual boot computer. Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, sound, soundcard

I'm running a **dual boot** computer with **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Windows 10**. The sound on my computer has been working normally up until yesterday. I  closed the computer lid and left to do something else, when I came back and opened it the sound stopped working. I only get a **dummy output** label on the sound output device. If I log into Windows, it can't find any sound output there either. I tried connecting normal headphones to the computer, but still I get no sound. Bluetooth headphones do work. Since the problem seems to be on both operating systems, **I think the problem is with the sound card.**

**I'm trying to find out if I need to install a new sound card, or if there is something I can do to fix this issue.** I think that since the sound does not work on Windows either, it is the sound card that is the problem. But I want to ask someone that might have a better grasp of this than I do.

To begin with I have to be honest and say that I tried lots of stuff I found online before I started documenting it. I used to (only checked this after the problem started) get something of the order

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

-- No sound card detected---
```

The file has since been deleted by something I've done.

I tried doing the

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

routine that I see in some solutions. Doing this used to run fine, but did not fix my problem. Now I get

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I think this issue started after removing some old linux kernel headers using `sudo apt autoremove`. Running `dpkg --configure -a` starts the uninstall and install but it never finishes.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Removing old oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  oem-audio-hda-daily
Version: 0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1
Kernel:  4.15.0-43-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod.......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.15.0-43-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-43-generic
```

The terminal then hangs on this last line and nothing happens. Even after an hour nothing happens. The process can't be stopped or paused using CTRl+C or Z.  I'm thinking that maybe it is trying to do something with the sound card and it doesn't work so it fails. **Any ideas here?**

## **Has anyone experienced a similar problem? Or does anyone know how I can fix this?**

---

---

Here are some outputs from my terminal:

```
sudo aplay -l

aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

---

```
pulseaudio

E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

---

```
sudo alsa force-reload

Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

---

```
pacmd list-sinks

sink(s) available.
index: 0
name: <auto_null>
driver: <module-null-sink.c>
flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE 
priority: 1000
volume: front-left: 35388 /  54% / -16.06 dB,   front-right: 35388 /  54% / -16.06 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 344 KiB
max rewind: 344 KiB
monitor source: 0
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
module: 11
properties:
    device.description = "Dummy Output"
    device.class = "abstract"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

---

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
Memory at a4428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at a4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to more or less have fixed itself. One day when I booted back into Windows I received a message from my computer to reboot, and I did. When I came back the sound was working normally. I'm guessing it installed a driver, although I had already checked for driver issues when the problem first began. When I booted back into Ubuntu, I had sound on only the left side. I still had the same problem with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as before. I uninstalled oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms, reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio, and now it works normally.